# Job started from cron got killed

Tags: linux, bash, process, cron

I started a java process from a cron job using this command

This is my cron entry

```
* * * * * sh /tmp/runScript.sh
```

The purpose of runScript.sh are to apply some logic and start a java process.

```
./runJavaProcess.sh >> java_process.out 2>&1
```

The job is got killed automatically with no entry in the java_process.out or in the java logs.
I am unable to see anything in the *kern.log* or */var/log/messages* or */var/log/messages* related to how the process got killed.

I can see that the process is starting fine, but after a few minutes/hours it is getting killed without any trace of why or how it got killed. Is there some way to find out the reason why the process got killed.

I'm running CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core).

Comment: Welcome aboard. You might get more response on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It sounds like the [Linux OOM killer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html) at work, but that one dumps notices into /var/log/messages AFAIK.

Comment: Can you also try `dmesg -T | grep -i "killed process"`?

Comment: Nothing in dmesg -T | grep -i  "killed process" . Isn't this written to /var/log/messages as well ?

Comment: Weird. Can you write a java test program which allocates memory until it dies and use that? Just to check if that will trigger the OOM killer. Then you might add output all over your code ("I am at A", "I am at B", "I am at C", ..) to localize where it dies and if there is a pattern. If there is no external influence, it leaves flaws in the program, bugs in the jvm, bad memory hardware.. Hard to tell from here.

Comment: There's no mention of the OOM Killer in the Kern logs. It had come a couple of times in the past. In these scenarios there's no mention on the OOM Killer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause. There was a Segmentation Fault in the java process.
The error log was created in the /root/ directory.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f11f1b980e5, pid=22395, tid=0x00007f11b39be700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b15) (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 8563 C2 java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.getLong(I)J (16 bytes) @ 0x00007f11f1b980e5 [0x00007f11f1b980a0+0x45]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f12023f72a0):  JavaThread "BatchlogTasks:1" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=23777, stack(0x00007f11b397e000,0x00007f11b39bf000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x000000000fd68aae
```

Answer (score 1):

That `java_process.out` might exist in your home directory, i.e. `~/java_process.out`. Your script has only the file name and `cron` will execute in your home directory. Adding the path might help.

Comment: The file name is indicative, i have actually used the full path on my system. nothing in the log

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check `/var/log/cron`, not `/var/log/messages` to get some insight on what happened.
2. I suggest you edit your crontab entry as below in order to obtain the output of what's happening upon execution.

   ```
   * * * * * sh /tmp/runScript.sh 2>&1 /tmp/insight.log
   ```
3. It's possible that your `runJavaProcess.sh` script needs some environment variables to run, and unless you source them in the crontab line (or in your scripts) as below, it won't find them:

   ```
   * * * * *  . $HOME/.bash_profile; sh /tmp/runScript.sh 2>&1 /tmp/insight.log
   ```

Comment: Checked /var/log/cron also, it shows that the /tmp/runScript.sh was executed, but nothing about the process dying

Comment: OK, so your job dies and there is no output in the .out file. Are you sure your job dies prematurely? Can you output anything at all? You might add some test output at the begin of your job.

Comment: Nothing in the application logs shows any issue. No spike in any other system metrics noticed either.